# Is it possible to rotate nodes in editors?

Tags: node-editor

While arranging nodes, sometimes I would like the connections to wrap backwards. However, when doing this, if the angle is not 90deg you get this wrap around.

[image]

Is there any way to rotate this? I'd rather not be committed to 90deg angles.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid the only way to use "backwards non-90°" angles is to use straight noodles:
[image]

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Themes and adjust the noodle curving.

Comment: This will serve as an acceptable alternative.